# retrofit @POST parameters are sent via GET

Tags: android, json, http, retrofit

I am trying to send multiple parameters (as I usually do) with `@QueryMap` but via POST this time using retrofit.

Retrofit API

```
@POST("/request.php")
void sendRequest(@QueryMap Map<String, String> parameters, retrofit.Callback<RequestSendResponse> callback);
```

Map that is being send

```
public static Map<String, String> parametersSendRequest(Context sender, Request request)
{
    Map <String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    Operator operator = AppConfig.config().operator;

    parameters.put("user_name", request.user_name);
    parameters.put("user_surname", request.user_surname);
    parameters.put("user_gender", request.user_gender);
    parameters.put("user_relationship", request.user_relationship);
    parameters.put("user_dob", request.user_dob);
    parameters.put("operator_name", operator.name);
    parameters.put("request_photoid", request.request_photoid);
    parameters.put("request_user_content", request.request_user_content);
    parameters.put("request_title", request.request_title);
    parameters.put("uuid", UUID(sender));
    parameters.put("response_type", "json");
    parameters.put("platform", "android");
    parameters.put("mode", "send");

    return parameters;
}
```

Server result

```
{"POST":[],"GET":{"operator_name":....}}
```

I can see that even the method is sent to `POST`, `@QueryMap` causes these parameters to be sent over GET. Even when I use `@Body` instead of `@QueryMap`, retrofit converts my @QueryMap to a JSON object, which is not I want.

All I want to do is to send `param1=value1&param2=value2` on my request body, instead of a JSON object (Using my `Map<String, String>`)

Comment: `@Query` or `@QueryMap` is for query string params, you should use `@Body` or `@Field` for POST payload.

Comment: @hidro thanks for the tip which lead me to solution :)

Comment: I want full  retrofit @POST parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to send parameters using POST (`@FormUrlEncoded` and `@FieldMap`)

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/request.php")
void sendRequest(@FieldMap Map<String, String> parameters, retrofit.Callback<RequestSendResponse> callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/profile/")
void getUserProfile(@Field("whatever")String whatever, Callback<Response> callback);
```

Pay special attention to the final slash after "profile". I had problems because I was not adding it. Hope it helps.

Comment: @POST("/profile/") , here you dont need to apply / at the the end, that will taken care by retrofit lib itself